# Duda sobre concatenar valores de un elemento input

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, concat

me encuentro con una duda sobre como concatenar los atributos 'value' de un grupo de elementos input.

El código es el siguiente:
HTML:

```
 <label><input type="checkbox" id="OWrite" value="400" class='checks' checked> Write</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="ORead" value="200" class='checks' checked > Read</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="OExec" value="100" class='checks'checked> Execute</label>
```

Jquery:

```
$('input[class="checks"]:checked').each(function() {
    console.log(parseInt(this.value))
```

});

El resultado:

> 400 200 100

Mi intención es sumar estos 3 valores, o en caso de ser un string concatenarlos, pero no logro seleccionarlos ya que me los devuelve todos juntos.
Agradezco su ayuda, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear una variable y guardar la suma de cada uno de los input

```
var myVar = 0;
$('input[class="checks"]:checked').each(function() {
    myVar = myVar + parseInt(this.value)        
});
console.log(myVar)
```

Comment: Buenas tardes, mucha gracias por la pronta respuesta pero no soluciona mi inquietud el código me quedo de la siguiente manera:

var myVar=0;
$('input[class="checks"]:checked').each(function() {
  myVar = myVar + parseInt(this.value)   
  console.log(myVar)

pero el resultado:
400
600
700
740

Aunque el ultimo de los resultados es la suma que busco, necesito como respuesta un unico resultado en este caso 740

Comment: Prueba usando el console.log() fuera de la función

Comment: @FrancoGaluzzi ahí modifiqué el código con el lugar en el que debería mostrar por consola

Comment: Excelente Matias, muchisimas gracias, por curiosidad, para saber si estoy errado, la función each() crea una especie de loop? por eso me repetía los log si no lo sacaba de la función?

Comment: En efecto, each() es un loop que recorre uno por uno los elementos que el selector encontró y realiza el código ahí dentro con cada uno de ellos.

Comment: creo que esto no responde a la pregunta, tenemos que queremos hacer dos cosas en función de los parámetros de entrmeada, si se trata de números sumar, y hasta ahí bien. El problema que veo a esta solución es que se sugiere que los parámetros pueden no ser números sino string, entonces no entiendo por qué el parse, dado que en este caso no es necesario